# Visual Studio always rebuilds solution with Paket

Tags: c#, visual-studio, paket

I'm very interested in using Paket instead of Nuget for my Packages in Visual Studio.

That works so far also fine. But the issue is, that Visual Studio always thinks that the app.config of each project has been changed. But looking into my changes in my Git Tool there is no change. Even if I directly build before running for example my Unit Test.

Do you have any suggestions?

My paket.dependencies looks like this:

```
// Only the target frameworks that are used in projects.
framework: net461
content: none

source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
source http://myownnugetrepo.com/nexus/

nuget SharpZipLib 0.86.0
nuget Autofac.WebApi2.Owin
nuget My.Own.Package redirects: on
nuget EasyNetQ.DI.Autofac
nuget EFInteractiveViews
nuget ExcelDataReader.DataSet
nuget FluentAssertions
nuget Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost 
nuget Microsoft.CSharp
nuget Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource
nuget Microsoft.Graph
nuget Microsoft.Identity.Client
nuget Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory 
nuget Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah
nuget NSubstitute
nuget NUnit
nuget Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework
nuget RestSharp.Newtonsoft.Json.Extensions 
nuget Serilog.Sinks.Async
nuget Serilog.Sinks.Console
nuget Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile
nuget Swashbuckle
nuget Topshelf.Serilog
```

What Visual Studio say (if building with Diagonistic mode):

> Project 'My.Project' is not up to date. Input file 'C:\Projects\My.Project\src\My.Project.Interface\app.config' is modified after output file ''.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it. After sleeping about this I found a Paket command to do this:

```
paket auto-restore on
```

This solved my issue. I thought it was automatically done by converting the Project from nuget to paket, but it wasn't. Now it works.